# Unity 3D Console says: Syntax error, '(' expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, syntax

**I am very new to c#, I'm sorry for any of my confusion.**
I have been using Unity for around a week now, I have tried lots of things I know of and nothing is working. Thanks in advance!!

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Utility
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (UI.text))]
    public class FPSCounter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        const float fpsMeasurePeriod = 0.5f;
        private int m_FpsAccumulator = 0;
        private float m_FpsNextPeriod = 0;
        private int m_CurrentFps;
        const string display = "{0} FPS";
        private UI.text m_UI.text;


        private void Start()
        {
            m_FpsNextPeriod = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + fpsMeasurePeriod;
            m_UI.text = GetComponent<UI.text>();
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            // measure average frames per second
            m_FpsAccumulator++;
            if (Time.realtimeSinceStartup > m_FpsNextPeriod)
            {
                m_CurrentFps = (int) (m_FpsAccumulator/fpsMeasurePeriod);
                m_FpsAccumulator = 0;
                m_FpsNextPeriod += fpsMeasurePeriod;
                m_UI.text.text = string.Format(display, m_CurrentFps);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Errors From Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJaO9.jpg)

Comment: Presumably this line`private UI.text m_UI.text;` You can't use a `.` in an identifier as far as I know. Try just `m_UIText` and change it in the other places you use it too.

Comment: Also, `UI.text` is not a valid type, Text should start with capital `T`, so: `UI.Text`. Or you can add `using UnityEngine.UI;` on top of the script so you can simple use `Text` instead of `UI.Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of [Redired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68280371/unity-3d-console-says-syntax-error-expected/68282080#comment120675448_68280371) is right, you cannot use `.` in a variable name. But you can use `_`.

Here is the basic rule for variable naming from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/gg615485(v=vs.88)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#variable-naming) :

> The first character of a variable name must be either a letter, an underscore  character (_), or the at symbol (@).
>
> Subsequent characters may be letters, underscore characters, or numbers.
>
> There are also certain keywords that have a specialized meaning to the C# compiler

There is also another thing that could produce an error in your code:

Starting at the line `[RequireComponent(typeof (UI.text))]`, you are using `UI.text` with `text` in lowercase. *If it is not* the `UnityEngine.UI` that’s at use here, it is fine.
But if it’s what you are trying to use, the correct syntax would be `UI.Text`, with a uppercase `T`.

Letter case matters in types and variables names.

Also, if you want to avoid using `UI.Text` each time, you could also add the line `using UnityEngine.Text;` under the first using statement, at the top of your file. Then, you could rewrite `[RequireComponent(typeof (UI.text))]` as `[RequireComponent(typeof (Text))]`.

---

Edit: It seem that [kolodi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68280371/unity-3d-console-says-syntax-error-expected/68282080#comment120677548_68280371) commented on `UI.Text` part of my answer while I was writting it.